# copy file from AWS S3 (as static website) to AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have URL for downloading report from external S3 like:

```
https://nmd-externalreports.s3.amazonaws.com/name_reports/report_date%3D2022-02-20/lvl_id%3D74557/med_id%3D246797/user_report_raw_v2.csv?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220222T121150Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Credential=CRED1234%2F20220222%2EU-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=1t6b9a71c8b0c1c6e214f3e5737dacba68e
```

Usually it is a big files, 1-2 GB.
I try make it using temp file, but processing takes a lot of time, 20 minutes per file:

```
        with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as report:
        report.write(requests.get(URL).content)

        report.flush()
        report.seek(0)

        # upload to S3
        bucket, key = self.get_s3_path(start, end, lvl_id, os_name)
        self.s3.Object(bucket, key).put(Body=report)
```

How can I copy files to my S3 using python or AWS CLI without pre-processing?

Comment: This is not possible, at most you can do streaming and download and upload in chunks at the same time.

Comment: @maxMiller Thanks,  looks like this solution will work for me